# Postgres pg_try_advisory_lock blocks all records

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking

I'm using `pg_try_advisory_lock()` in Postgres.

Next two queries lock more than one records in `table1`:

1)

```
SELECT a.id
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.table1_id = b.id
WHERE
    table2.id = 1
    AND
    pg_try_advisory_lock('table1'::regclass::integer, a.id)
LIMIT 1;
```

but

```
SELECT a.id
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.table1_id = b.id
WHERE table2.id = 1
```

returns one record.

2)

```
SELECT a.id
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.table1_id = b.id
JOIN table3 c ON b.table2_id = c.id
WHERE
    table3.id = 1
    AND
    pg_try_advisory_lock('table1'::regclass::integer, a.id)
LIMIT 1;
```

But I need `pg_try_advisory_lock()` to lock only one record.

What's wrong?

**UPD**

But the strange thing is that when I run the following query

```
SELECT a.id
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.table1_id = b.id
WHERE
    pg_try_advisory_lock('table1'::regclass::integer, a.id)
LIMIT 1;
```

Postgres locks only one row. So, Postgres scans the very first row then stops? I don't get it: it should scan all rows then limit the results to one row, or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling pg_try_advisory_lock() once per row in the entire set that gets scanned (as part of the filtering that occurs in the `where` clause), whereas you only want it called once per row in table1 returned by the query.

You could try using a subquery or a CTE instead:

```
with rows as (
SELECT a.id
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.table1_id = b.id
WHERE table2.id = 1
)
select rows.*
from rows
where pg_try_advisory_lock('table1'::regclass::integer, rows.id);
```

But don't rely on that to necessarily work as expected either: Postgres should be tempted to rewrite it the way your initial query was.

Another possibility is this, since the `select` part of a statement is evaluated very late in the query:

```
with rows as (
SELECT a.id,
       pg_try_advisory_lock('table1'::regclass::integer, a.id) as locked
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.table1_id = b.id
WHERE table2.id = 1
)
select rows.id
from rows
where rows.locked;
```

The real issue in practice is that `pg_try_advisory_lock()` is something you'd normally find in app land or in a function, rather than in a query like you're doing. Speaking of which, depending on what you're doing, are you sure you shouldn't be using `select … for update`?

---

Regarding your update:

> postgres scans the very first row then stops?

Yes. Due to the `limit 1`, it's going to find a match and immediately stop. What is probably happening, though, is that it's not evaluating the `where` clause in the same order depending on your queries. SQL offers no guarantee that the `a <> 0` part in `a <> 0 and b / a > c` gets evaluated first. Applied to your case, it offers no guarantee that the advisory lock is obtained *after* the row from a is joined with b.

Comment: I don't need select … for update because another script must find another records.

Comment: I still think you should be locking in app-land, rather than in sql-land.

Comment: CTE works good. Thanks for advice!
Also I updated question. See plz.

Comment: Double check its query plan, though, using `explain analyze`. For your query to work as expected, Postgres *must* evaluate the CTE first, rather than rewrite it like it was in your original query. And if anything, I'd argue that Postgres would be wrong to not rewrite it. :-)